# How to take count of data in flat table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a flat table consists of thousands of rows and more that ten columns. I want to take count for each column(not null) for each row.
For example, here i have flat table say `table A` :

```
+=====+======+======+======+=====+======+
| Aid | col1 | col2 | col3 | ... |col10 |
+=====+======+======+======+=====+======+
|  1  |   a  |   b  |   c  | ... |   x  |
+-----+------+------+------+-----+------+
|  2  |   a  |   b  |   c  | ... |   x  |
+-----+------+------+------+-----+------+
|  3  |   a  |   b  |   c  | ... |   x  |
+-----+------+------+------+-----+------+
```

Now, i want to take count for all columns(not null) for all Aid in single query.
For example if i take count for col1 then i need to use 
`select count(*) from A where col1 is not null;`
But i want all column count(not null values) for each Aid in table in single query.
How could i do that?

Comment: What do you mean for each `Aid` ? in your example it's unique...

Comment: yes, Aid is unique..I want say for Aid 1 count of values is 10 if all column consist some value and 9 if one column consists null value and others have some value.

Comment: OK, now your question is clear - you want to count columns which contain values for every row.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [COUNT function documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions039.htm#i82697):

> If you specify *expr*, then COUNT returns the number of rows where *expr* is not null.

Therefore you can use:

```
select aid, count(col1), count(col2), count(col3)
  from t
 group by aid
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider following query

```
select count(a), count(b), count(c)....
  from table_name
```

or

```
select count(distinct a), count(distinct b), count(distinct c), ...
  from table_name
```

if you want to count distinct values

Answer (score 0):

Marco's answer is perfect. If your table is huge and an approximation of the count is OK, you might as well have a look at the data dictionary. Everytime you (or your DBA) calls DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS, it collects exactly those counts and stores them in a view:

```
SELECT column_name, num_nulls 
  FROM user_tab_columns 
 WHERE table_name='A';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 11g you can use [unpivot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) and then count with a group by on Aid:

```
select aid,count(*) 
from tablea
unpivot
(
  vals for col_name in (col1, col2, col3, ..., col10)
  )
group by aid
order by aid
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/484fb/7)